# How to highlight repeated occurrences of selection text in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I've been working with Notepad++ and a really wonderful feature of that is that it highlights repeat occurrences of selection text.

But ever since I installed Notepad++ 4.1.2 that feature is not there.

How do I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

4.1.2 was an older version. Installed V6 and issue fixed